# button for getting current location?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

}

Hi everyone I have this code here which displays, I need to add a button so when its clicked i would be able to get the user's current location. Any advice on how to do that ? I know how to add the button and set the onclicklistener, I just dont know how to get the users current location. So when the button is clicked lets say a marker gets drawn on the users current location. Any advice ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this demo for getting current location:[http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get user's location, you need to add a LocationListener.
You must select a provider, either **GPS** or **Network**, and get the user's location.

You also need to add permissions too into your manifest xml.

I have already worked on such kind of a project. I can give you the code if you want.
Send me your email ID if yes.